# When are all sums of the elements of a set different?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Consider a set $S = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\} \subset \mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ and assume that for any $I, J \subset [n]$ with $I \neq J$ we have that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in I} x_i \neq \sum_{j \in J} x_j
\end{equation}

I would like to know if sets of this form have a name (possibly changing $\mathbb{Q}$ for $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$), or if there are any known conditions to ensure that $S$ satisfies this condition with some probability.

For example, this holds almost surely for $\mathbb{R}$ if the elements in $S$ are drawn from a continuous distribution, but I am interested in the other cases.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you require I and J to have empty intersection?

Comment: Related: https://oeis.org/A201052

Comment: @joro No, I and J can intersect as long as I \neq J.

Comment: OK. If you disallow intersection, it is NP-complete over the naturals.

Comment: There may be no better name than [distinct subset sums](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/sets_with_distinct_subset_sums).

Comment: It does not matter whether you allow $I$ and $J$ to intersect, as replacing $I$ by $I \setminus J$ and $J$ by $J \setminus I$ will preserve equality.

Comment: In the additive combinatorics literature such sets are called ``dissociated".

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they are very insightful! @joro I'm not concerned about the computability of the decision problem, I just need to know if the set satisfies the distinct subset sums property with some probability!

Comment: From rationals you can scale to integers by multiplying by the lcm of the denominators. If all integers are positive and $\sum x_i < 2^n$ I think there are two equal sum subsets.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding conditions to decide.

It is NP-complete over the positive integers.

As pointed by Ben Barber, "It does not matter whether you allow $I$ and $J$ to intersect, as replacing $I$ by $I \setminus J$ and $J$ by $J \setminus I$ will preserve equality."

[ON THE COMPLEXITY OF VARIATIONS OF EQUAL SUM SUBSETS, p. 1](http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~pagour/papers/NJC09.pdf)

> The Equal Sum Subsets problem, where we are given a set of positive integers
>   and we ask for two nonempty disjoint subsets such that their elements add up to the same total, is known to be NP-hard.

Also related is [OEIS A201052 a(n) is the maximal number c of integers that can be chosen from {1,2,...,n} so that all 2^c subsets have distinct sums.](https://oeis.org/A201052)